# Django: Storing huge matrix in table or in a file?

Tags: django, database, file, storage

I use Django to manage a machine learning process. At the end of the calculation stage, I'm left with a huge matrix data (~50MB of floats). Should I store it in my Django model (binary field?) or in a file (FileField)? It seems there are pros and cons for the two alternatives.

My specific case: I just need to write the data once the training is finished and load it in memory each time I want to use the learned model. No query. Just read entire data in matrix and write matrix in table/file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for asking back!!

I am adapting my answer according to your use-case.

Since you just need to write data each time after training,You should try [this](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1669/)

Comment: Thanks Gautam,I feel it's a little bit overkill, isn't it? My concern was not about speed or performance, I just want to store a matrix and the question was: where? (read on the net: "Don't start using Redis or any other cache until you need the speed - don't prematurely optimize")

Comment: It works. I write numbers with commas separating columns, and semicolons separating rows. Afterward, I can load my data in a matrix with numpy.matrix(data). I don't know if it's very efficient but it works. Thank you Gautam.